# CV with friggeri-cv - Alignment of section header

Tags: header-footer, cv, friggeri-cv

Currently I create my CV and use this as my [Template](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/smart-fancy-cv) based on the `friggeri-cv.cls` class. Unfortunately I can not find the settings for the text of each header in a section. I wanna bring header 'Education' in line with 'Experience' and 'Reference'. I predict there is blank space somewhere but I can not spot it.

I attached my modified `friggeri-cv` file and the `cv.tex`.

[image: Compiled]

`CV.tex`:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[nodayofweek,level]{datetime}
\newcommand{\mydate}{\today}
\setitemize{leftmargin=*}
% if you want to add fontawesome package
% you need to compile the tex file with LuaLaTeX
% References:
%   http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/fontawesome/fontawesome.pdf
%   https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fontawesome?lang=en
%\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{metalogo}
\usepackage{dtklogos}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shadows}
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={},
    pdfauthor={},
    pdfsubject={},
    pdfkeywords={},
    colorlinks=false,           % no lik border color
    allbordercolors=white       % white border color for all
}
\smartdiagramset{
    bubble center node font = \footnotesize,
    bubble node font = \footnotesize,
    % specifies the minimum size of the bubble center node
    bubble center node size = 0.5cm,
    %  specifies the minimum size of the bubbles
    bubble node size = 0.5cm,
    % specifies which is the distance among the bubble center node and the other bubbles
    distance center/other bubbles = 0.3cm,
    % sets the distance from the text to the border of the bubble center node
    distance text center bubble = 0.5cm,
    % set center bubble color
    bubble center node color = pblue,
    % define the list of colors usable in the diagram
    set color list = {lightgray, materialcyan, orange, green, materialorange, materialteal, materialamber, materialindigo, materialgreen, materiallime},
    % sets the opacity at which the bubbles are shown
    bubble fill opacity = 0.6,
    % sets the opacity at which the bubble text is shown
    bubble text opacity = 0.5,
}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{pblue}{HTML}{0395DE}

\begin{document}
\header{John}{ Smith}
      {Computer Engineer}

% Fake text to add separator      
\fcolorbox{white}{gray}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
.....
}}

% In the aside, each new line forces a line break
\begin{aside}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.18]{img/snow_circle.png}
  %\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{img/circleBioPic.png}
  \section{Address}
    BLA
    ~
  \section{Tel \& Skype}
    BLA
    ~
  \section{Mail}
    \href{BLA}{BLA}
    ~
%  \section{Web \& Git}
%    \href{http://mywebsite.com}{mywebsite.com}
  % use  \hspace{} or \vspace{} to change bubble size, if needed
  \section{Programming}
    \smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{
        \textbf{BLA},
        %\textbf{Java-}\\\textbf{script},
        \\\textbf{}\textbf{C++}\\\textbf{},
        \textbf{BLA}\\\textbf{BLA},
        \textbf{BLA},
        \textbf{BLA} \\\textbf{BLA},
        \textbf{BLA},
        \textbf{BLA},
        \textbf{BLA} 
    }
    ~
\end{aside}
~
\section{Education}
\begin{entrylist}
    \entry
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    \entry
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    \entry
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    \entry
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
\end{entrylist}
%~
\section{Experience}
\begin{entrylist}
      \entry
      {BLA}
      {BLA}
      {\\BLA}
      {BLA}
  \entry
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    {BLA}{BLA
        }
\end{entrylist}
%~
\section{References}
\begin{entrylist}
    \entry
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    \entry
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
\end{entrylist}

\end{document}
```

`friggeri-cv.cls`:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% 
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ProvidesClass{friggeri-cv}[2012/04/30 CV class]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\DeclareOption{print}{\def\@cv@print{}}
\DeclareOption*{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}%
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}


%%%%%%%%%%
% Colors %
%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\definecolor{darkgray}{HTML}{333333}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{4D4D4D}
\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{999999}
\definecolor{green}{HTML}{C2E15F}
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{FDA333}
\definecolor{purple}{HTML}{D3A4F9}
\definecolor{red}{HTML}{FB4485}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{6CE0F1}
\definecolor{pblue}{HTML}{0395DE}
\definecolor{materialpurple}{HTML}{9C27B0}
\definecolor{materialindigo}{HTML}{3F51B5}
\definecolor{materialblue}{HTML}{2196F3}
\definecolor{materialcyan}{HTML}{00BCD4}
\definecolor{materialteal}{HTML}{009688}
\definecolor{materialgreen}{HTML}{4CAF50}
\definecolor{materiallime}{HTML}{CDDC39}
\definecolor{materialamber}{HTML}{FFC107}
\definecolor{materialbrown}{HTML}{795548}
\definecolor{materialred}{HTML}{FF4436}
\definecolor{materialorange}{HTML}{FF5722}

\ifdefined\@cv@print
  \colorlet{green}{gray}
  \colorlet{orange}{gray}
  \colorlet{purple}{gray}
  \colorlet{red}{gray}
  \colorlet{blue}{gray}
  \colorlet{fillheader}{white}
  \colorlet{header}{gray}
\else
  \colorlet{fillheader}{white}
  \colorlet{header}{gray}
\fi
\colorlet{textcolor}{gray}
\colorlet{headercolor}{gray}


%%% modified by Karol Kozioł for ShareLaTex use
\RequirePackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\RequirePackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}

\newfontfamily\bodyfont
[BoldFont=texgyreheros-bold.otf,
ItalicFont=texgyreheros-italic.otf,
BoldItalicFont=texgyreheros-bolditalic.otf]
{texgyreheros-regular.otf}
\newfontfamily\thinfont[]{Lato-Hairline.ttf}
\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{texgyreheros-bold.otf}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont
[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor,
BoldFont=texgyreheros-bold.otf,
ItalicFont=texgyreheros-italic.otf,
BoldItalicFont=texgyreheros-bolditalic.otf
]
{texgyreheros-regular.otf}%

\setmathfont{texgyreheros-regular.otf}%
%%%

%%%%%%%%%%
% Header %
%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\rolefont}{%
  \fontsize{14pt}{24pt}\selectfont%
  \thinfont%
  \color{white}%
}

\newcommand{\header}[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    \node [rectangle, fill=fillheader, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=3cm] (box) at (current page.north){};%
    \node [anchor=center] (name) at (box) {%
      \fontsize{30pt}{62pt}\color{header}%
      {\thinfont #1}{\bodyfont  #2}%
    };%
    \node [anchor=north] at (name.south) {%
      \fontsize{14pt}{24pt}\color{pblue}%
      \bodyfont #3%
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \vspace{0.5cm}%
  \vspace{-2\parskip}%
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Structure %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage{parskip}%


\newcounter{colorCounter}%
\def\@sectioncolor#1#2#3{%
  {%
    \color{%
      \ifcase\value{colorCounter}%
        pblue\or%
        pblue\or%
        pblue\or%
        pblue\or%
        pblue\else%
        pblue\fi%
    } #1#2#3%
  }%
  \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{%
  %\par\vspace{\parskip} 
  \vspace{1mm}%
  {%
    \LARGE\headingfont\color{headercolor}%
    \@sectioncolor #1%
  }\\ \vspace{2mm}%
}

\renewcommand{\subsection}[2]{%
  \par\vspace{.5\parskip}%
  \Large\headingfont\color{headercolor} #2%
  \par\vspace{.25\parskip}%
}%

\pagestyle{empty}%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% List environment %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}}{%
  \end{tabular*}}%
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}%
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
%  #1&\parbox[t]{11.8cm}{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{12.6cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=pblue} #3}%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Side block %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}%
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}%
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}%
\newenvironment{aside}{%
  \let\oldsection\section%
  \renewcommand{\section}[1]{%
    \par\vspace{\baselineskip}{\Large\headingfont\color{pblue} ##1}%
  }%
  %\begin{textblock}{3.6}(2, 0.55)
  \begin{textblock}{3.6}(1.2, 0.55)%
  \begin{flushright}%
  \obeycr%
}{%
  \restorecr%
  \end{flushright}%
  \end{textblock}%
  \let\section\oldsection%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Bibliography %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage[style=verbose, maxnames=99, sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}%

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1\par}%
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{title}{#1\par}%
\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{#1\par}%
\DeclareFieldFormat[report]{title}{#1\par}%

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}\itshape%
    \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
    \setunit{\space}%
    \printfield{pages}%
    \newunit%
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \newunit%
  }%
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}%
}%

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}%
    \printfield{booktitle}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{location}%
    \newunit%
  }%
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}%
}%

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{misc}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}\itshape%
    \printfield{booktitle}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{note}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{location}%
    \newunit%
  }%
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}%
}%

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{report}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}\itshape%
    \printfield{type}%
    \setunit{\space}%
    \printfield{number}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \newunit%
  }%
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}%
}%

\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
  \small\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}%
  \ifblank{##3}{}{##3\space}#1%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}%
    {\addcomma\space}%
    {}%
}

\newcommand{\printbibsection}[2]{%
  \begin{refsection}%
    \nocite{*}%
    \printbibliography[sorting=chronological, type={#1}, title={#2}, heading=subbibliography]%
  \end{refsection}%
}

\DeclareSortingScheme{chronological}{%
  \sort[direction=descending]{\field{year}}%
  \sort[direction=descending]{\field{month}}%
}%



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Other tweaks %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\RequirePackage[left=6.1cm,top=2cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2.0cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\RequirePackage[left=5.3cm,top=2cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2.0cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}%
\RequirePackage{hyperref}%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just comment the `~` before command `\section{Education}`:

```
\end{aside}
%~ % <==================================================================
\section{Education}
```

The complete MWE

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv1} % <===========================================
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[nodayofweek,level]{datetime}
\newcommand{\mydate}{\today}
\setitemize{leftmargin=*}
% if you want to add fontawesome package
% you need to compile the tex file with LuaLaTeX
% References:
%   http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/fontawesome/fontawesome.pdf
%   https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fontawesome?lang=en
%\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{metalogo}
%\usepackage{dtklogos}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shadows}
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={},
    pdfauthor={},
    pdfsubject={},
    pdfkeywords={},
    colorlinks=false,           % no lik border color
    allbordercolors=white       % white border color for all
}
\smartdiagramset{
    bubble center node font = \footnotesize,
    bubble node font = \footnotesize,
    % specifies the minimum size of the bubble center node
    bubble center node size = 0.5cm,
    %  specifies the minimum size of the bubbles
    bubble node size = 0.5cm,
    % specifies which is the distance among the bubble center node and the other bubbles
    distance center/other bubbles = 0.3cm,
    % sets the distance from the text to the border of the bubble center node
    distance text center bubble = 0.5cm,
    % set center bubble color
    bubble center node color = pblue,
    % define the list of colors usable in the diagram
    set color list = {lightgray, materialcyan, orange, green, materialorange, materialteal, materialamber, materialindigo, materialgreen, materiallime},
    % sets the opacity at which the bubbles are shown
    bubble fill opacity = 0.6,
    % sets the opacity at which the bubble text is shown
    bubble text opacity = 0.5,
}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{pblue}{HTML}{0395DE}

\begin{document}
\header{John}{ Smith}
      {Computer Engineer}

% Fake text to add separator      
\fcolorbox{white}{gray}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
.....
}}

% In the aside, each new line forces a line break
\begin{aside}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.18]{example-image-a} % 
  %\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{img/circleBioPic.png}
  \section{Address}
    BLA
    ~
  \section{Tel \& Skype}
    BLA
    ~
  \section{Mail}
    \href{BLA}{BLA}
    ~
%  \section{Web \& Git}
%    \href{http://mywebsite.com}{mywebsite.com}
  % use  \hspace{} or \vspace{} to change bubble size, if needed
  \section{Programming}
    \smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{
        \textbf{BLA},
        %\textbf{Java-}\\\textbf{script},
        \\\textbf{}\textbf{C++}\\\textbf{},
        \textbf{BLA}\\\textbf{BLA},
        \textbf{BLA},
        \textbf{BLA} \\\textbf{BLA},
        \textbf{BLA},
        \textbf{BLA},
        \textbf{BLA} 
    }
    ~
\end{aside}
%~ % <==================================================================
\section{Education}
\begin{entrylist}
    \entry
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    \entry
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    \entry
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    \entry
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
\end{entrylist}
%~
\section{Experience}
\begin{entrylist}
      \entry
      {BLA}
      {BLA}
      {\\BLA}
      {BLA}
  \entry
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    {BLA}{BLA
        }
\end{entrylist}
%~
\section{References}
\begin{entrylist}
    \entry
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    \entry
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
    {BLA}
\end{entrylist}

\end{document}
```

Please note that I renamed your changed file of friggeri cv to `friggeri-cv1.cls`. Please do not change original files, copy it and change the copy stored with a new name.

The result you get:

[image]